# How to rerender items in Ui when Filtered is applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Here is the deal. when page renders I am firing useEffect and displaying fetched Data.
using function determineWhatToMap(). In context I am filtering specific category's array and setting sorted state and returning. Now I want to display That sorted arrays Items,
Any time that useEffect changes.I can not figure out what to write in`else` and `right-d` to achive this.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useGlobalContext } from '../context'
import {FaSearch,FaPlusCircle} from 'react-icons/fa'
import Filter from '../components/filters/Filter'


export default function SingleCategory() {

  const {categoryName} = useParams()

  const {meat,setMeat,fish,setFish,veg,setVeg,custom,setCustom,sorted} = useGlobalContext()
 
  const determineWhatToMap = (categoryName) =>{

    if(categoryName === "Meat"){
      return meat
    }else if(categoryName === "Fish"){
     return fish

    }else if(categoryName === "Vegetable"){
      return veg
 
    }
  }
  

  const determineCategory = (response, categoryName) =>{
    if(categoryName === "Meat" && meat?.length === 0){
      
      setMeat(response)
    }else if(categoryName === "Fish" && fish?.length === 0){
     
     setFish(response)

    }else if(categoryName === "Vegetable" && veg?.length === 0){
     
      setVeg(response)
 
    }
  }

  const determineFetch = (catName) =>{
    if(catName === "Meat"){
      return ["Beef","Chicken"]
    }else if(catName === "Fish"){
      console.log("hit")
      return ["SeaFood"]
    }else if(catName === "Vegetable"){
      return ["Vegetarian","Vegan"]
    }else{
      
    }
  }


  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async () =>{
      const response = await Promise.all(determineFetch(categoryName)?.map((el)=>{
      
        return fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=${el}`).then(response => response.json())
      }))
     
      determineCategory(response,categoryName)

    }

    if(determineWhatToMap(categoryName)?.length === 0){
  
      fetchData()

    }else{
      // this must trigger reload
    }
   
  },[categoryName,sorted])

  return (
    <section className='single_category_init'>
       <h1>Expore <strong className='emph'>{categoryName}</strong> Category</h1>
      <p>Happy cooking</p>
      <div className='filter_recipes'>
        <div className='l-side'>
          <Filter category={categoryName}/>
        </div>
        <div className='r-side'>
          {/* map filtered or initial array*/}
        </div>
      </div> 
    </section>
  )
}
```